# My website is not indexed in Google search console but yet i can see its performance

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I choose the Domain option in the Google search console and added my url there with the sitemap. My page is still not indexed. Because when I search the site: myurl.com nothing shows up. But when I go into the performance section of the Google search console I can see that my site has 18 impressions and 2 clicks. I can also see the top queries. Can you tell me why is this happening?

24 hrs have passed since I requested indexing and yet there is no result. It just shows "Processing data, please check again in a day or so"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the SEO tag states: GENERAL SEO QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com. Please delete your question here first.

Answer (score 0):

The site: search is not a reliable way to determine indexing. It only shows a sample of pages in the index.

Focus on the reports in the Search Console. They can also be delayed.